# Added Onclick Java Script Alert into Detail Page Button

Tags: javascript, custom-button, button, onclick

I am encountering some issues and it has me stumped, and hoping the community can help me out.

The aim here is that when the user pushes the custom button an alert should pop up saying:

> "By Pressing Ok,The following will be sent to the external Provider"

When the user pushes the alert "okay" the `Approve__c` field set to true. If the User tries to push the button again and the `Approve__c` is set to true an other alert says "Already been sent to Supplier"

This is my OnClick JavaScript code. The button updates the approve field, however an alert isn't being presented.

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/30.0/connection.js")} 
var newRecords = [];
var c = new sforce.SObject("sales_and_marketing__c"); 
c.id ="{!sales_and_marketing__c.Id}"; 

if (c.Approve__c == 0) 
    alert('By Pressing OK,the following details will be sent to the external Provider'); 

c.Approve__c = true; 
newRecords.push(c); 
result = sforce.connection.update(newRecords); 
window.location.reload();
```

Comment: Problem is that *c.Approve__c* is not actually queried from database. Only Id is. Try to get that from page (like {!sales_and_marketing__c.Approve__c}) or requery **c** object with that field included

Comment: @kurunve - do you have a basic example I can refer to

Comment: try instead of if (c.Approve__c == 0)  next: ("{! sales_and_marketing__c.Approve__c}"== 'false')